# how to delete all result from database in codeigniter model

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-4

sorry, im still learning code igniter4.
right now on my controller, i have this :

```
MyModel->where(['user_id' => $result['id'] , 'books_id' => $result['id']])->findAll();
```

i want to delete all the result from the method above. how to do that in CI?

Answer (score 1):

Using query builder:

```
$builder->emptyTable('mytable'); // Produces: DELETE FROM my
```

or use

```
$builder->truncate();
```

reference :https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/query_builder.html?highlight=delete

Answer (score 0):

i already solve this problem by using this code :

```
$tmp = $myModel->where(['user_id' => result[$id])->findAll();
$tmp = count($tmp);
while ($tmp != 0) {
      $myModel->where(['user_id' => result[$id]])->delete();
      $tmp = $tmp - 1;
}
```

because delete() doesn't work on array, i use this method